# leanback poster lost position after overriding the lb_fullwidth_details_overview_logo

Tags: android-tv, leanback

can you please help me to know how can I change the text below the poster in leanback details view content without losing the position?

[image]

this is the code I used:

lb_fullwidth_details_overview_logo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- This is an override of the full width details overview logo layout -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/details_overview_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:elevation="@dimen/lb_details_overview_z"
        android:maxHeight="@dimen/lb_details_v2_logo_max_height"
        android:maxWidth="@dimen/lb_details_v2_logo_max_width" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statusText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

CustomDetailsOverviewLogoPresenter

```
class CustomDetailsOverviewLogoPresenter(private val entitlementStatus: String) :
    DetailsOverviewLogoPresenter() {

    internal class ViewHolder(view: View?) :
        DetailsOverviewLogoPresenter.ViewHolder(view) {
        override fun getParentPresenter(): FullWidthDetailsOverviewRowPresenter {
            return mParentPresenter
        }

        override fun getParentViewHolder(): FullWidthDetailsOverviewRowPresenter.ViewHolder {
            return mParentViewHolder
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): Presenter.ViewHolder {
        val cardView = DetailsOverviewCardView(parent.context)
        val width: Int = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        val height: Int = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        cardView.layoutParams = MarginLayoutParams(width, height)
        return ViewHolder(cardView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: Presenter.ViewHolder, item: Any) {
        val row = item as DetailsOverviewRow
        val cardView = viewHolder.view as DetailsOverviewCardView
        val imageView = cardView.imageView
        val status = cardView.statusText
        status.text = entitlementStatus
        imageView.setImageDrawable(row.imageDrawable)
        if (isBoundToImage(viewHolder as ViewHolder, row)) {
            viewHolder.parentPresenter.notifyOnBindLogo(viewHolder.parentViewHolder)
        }
    }
}
```

but now the image is not in the position it must be

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `lb_fullwidth_details_overview.xml`. you need to modify this layout in order to change `FullWidthDetailsOverview`.

Comment: Thank you @mahdi, can you please guide me on how can I change that text programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom [DetailsOverviewLogoPresenter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/leanback/widget/DetailsOverviewLogoPresenter). When you construct your [FullWidthDetailsOverviewRowPresenter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/leanback/widget/FullWidthDetailsOverviewRowPresenter), the first parameter is the Presenter to use to render the description and the second one is the DetailsOverviewLogoPresenter.

In your DetailsOverviewLogoPresenter, implement onCreateView (to inflate and return the view you want to use), onCreateViewHolder (to wrap the returned view in a ViewHolder), and onBindViewHolder (to use the ViewHolder to set up the views including the image and your custom TextView's text).

The official sample has a [setupAdapter](https://github.com/android/tv-samples/blob/07929881d7684348de475f5c9c9d65f578605695/Leanback/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tvleanback/ui/VideoDetailsFragment.java#L184) method that shows how to create and use custom presenters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did it but it made another UI issue, as you can see the image is not in the position it must be. I updated the question with the latest code I am using